# Unidentified index when adding event to database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm attempting to add an event to a data base from Android. The errors I'm getting are for an unidentified index.

This is the error that was printed

**Notice**:  Undefined index: eventName in **/storage/ssd3/147/3824147/public_html/events.php** on line **4**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: eventWhere in **/storage/ssd3/147/3824147/public_html/events.php** on line **5**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: eventTime in **/storage/ssd3/147/3824147/public_html/events.php** on line **6**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: eventDesc in **/storage/ssd3/147/3824147/public_html/events.php** on line **7**

This is the events PHP

PHP is not exactly my forté but I cannot seem to solve this. The database has a table called 'eventInfo' where the rows are eventID, eventName, eventWhere, eventTime, eventDesc, user.

Comment: We can't help you with code we can't see. Please read [ask].